# plane vs diverging waves michelson itnerferometer

Tags: optics, interference, interferometry

I'm wondering if there's a difference in the interference pattern achieved in the michelson interferometer if the source of light is sending plane waves vs sending diverging waves (for example by putting a diverging lens between the source and the first plate, the one which divides the light).

Answer (score 1):

Plane waves are a theoretical construct as every aperture produces divergence, so you need an infinite amount of empty space to keep a plane wave plane.

As such every Michelson interferometer deals with diverging waves. These interferometers will take a divergent beam and collimate it before reciprocating the process so that sharp interference can still be seen.

A near exception is a fibre michelson interferometer where the waveguiding properties of the fibre act as collimation, though lensing is still needed to couple to the fibre.